# Why am I getting a `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'` Error

Tags: python, discord.py

It worked once then never again, I'm trying to load my log channel from a .env file which is working and loading fine, but when I go to send a log message to my log channel I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`

The ID is correct and I have given the bot explicit permission to send in that channel, but the error persists.

```
# Load Bot token
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
CHANNEL = os.getenv('LOG_CHANNEL')

# Set Bot command prefix
prefix = 'Q!'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)
channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL)
```

The .env file has `LOG_CHANNEL = 512123500123652096` and it loads it correctly, marking `CHANNEL` as int() doesn't help either

This is the first thing the bot does when it turns on

This is where I log, it's inside a command at the end

```
# Log command
command = discord.Embed(description=f"File unzipped in {ctx.channel.mention}", color=0x4040EC).set_author(name=ctx.author, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
command.add_field(name="File", value=f'{filename}')
command.timestamp = ctx.message.created_at
await channel.send(embed=command)
```

Comment: Even if I set the channel ID directly into `channel = bot.get_channel()` it throws the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of retrieving a channel is by using:

`bot.get_channel(id)`

If you are reading the channel id from a file it will be probably taking it as an string, you will need to convert it to int:

`channel = bot.get_channel(int(CHANNEL))`

It might also happen that `get_channel` returns `None` if your `CHANNEL` includes some extra spaces (maybe a space at the end). Make sure to double check that.

Comment: I've tried adding `int(CHANNEL)` and it still threw the error :( also just setting the ID with the actual ID returns `NONE`

Comment: Are you sure that ID of a channel exists in the server your bot is in?

Comment: This is so strange because no matter what channel ID I set it to it returns NONE like its cached somewhere and not letting go of it. changing the .env file to another and printing the CHANNEL var returns the old one

Comment: This might have something to do with not enabling your [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html). Make sure to enable them.

Comment: It seems calling `bot.get_channel()` within the command itself works with no issue, still strange how my .env var is stuck | If i call it within `on_ready()` the command doesnt recognize `channel` as a var

Comment: I did not think you would be using it in a different function. Of course it does not recognise `channel` as a variable, this is because it was never initialized in that function. Either read your .env in your function or save your `channel` as `bot.channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL)`

Comment: i wasn't calling it in there, it was just something I tried, but thank you for the help! :D